# Do high export resolutions compromise image safety?

Tags: lightroom, resolution, file-size, export

I specialize in macro photography and I've recently begun to export in 300-350dpi, as I find it does a better job of representing details (crucial to my work).

However the file size is small, eg. 1200px.

Am I compromising my image's safety? (given watermarks can be removed and files can be enlarged easily)

Comment: DPI is pretty much meaningless in a digital environment. 1200 pixels is 1200 pixels.

Comment: [Does the dpi number reported by camera in JPG have any meaning?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11182/15871)

Comment: [How does the dpi setting affect the image exported from Lightroom](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70855/15871)

Comment: [DPI in photos vs DPI in Printers/Scanners](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39072/15871)

Comment: What is "image safety"?

Comment: [What are the pros and cons of using a watermark?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38944/15871)

Comment: [Is watermarking worth it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/856/15871)

Comment: [How do you detect when your photos are used without copyright permission?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7272/15871)

Comment: [How do I remove a signature from a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45781/15871)

Comment: 1200px is not a file size. It is a dimension of one side of an image.

Comment: How are you using these files? The only place I know where DPI will make a difference is in Microsoft Word, where the default picture size on import is determined by the pixel dimensions divided by the DPI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An image doesn't have a DPI until you print it.

All it has are **dimensions** in pixels.

Anything else is simply an interpolation of one system to another in order to display on your screen... which is probably about 72dpi anyway.

If your image is 6000 x 4000 pixels, then that's its size, whatever dpi you think you may have saved it at.

Comment: _An image doesn't have a DPI until you print it._ +1. About the most succinct way I've seen it put.