# Do photographers commonly use watermarks?

Tags: copyright, watermark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is watermarking worth it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/856/is-watermarking-worth-it)

Are you concerned about image copy protection being a photographer or website owner? Are you interested in image watermarking software? If so then which one do you use?

Comment: related http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/856/is-watermarking-worth-it

Answer (score 2):

IMO, Watermark does very little to protect your images, unless you make it so hideous and ugly that it ruins the very image you want to protect.

Whenever I want to add watermark, I don't use a special software. I just use Photoshop.

Comment: Or GIMP, or whatever other editor you're already using.