# How do I remove a signature from a photo?

Tags: photo-editing, watermark

I have collected some photos from internet. I want to print them but the problem is that there is a signature of photographer in the photos. I want to remove those signatures. How can I do that?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to either pay the original photographers the fair market price to provide you with un-watermarked versions or to take your own photos instead of stealing them from others.

Comment: The reason there are watermarks (the signatures) on photographs is to stop people from doing exactly what you are doing, stealing someone else's intellectual property. This is a concept called copyright. The watermarks are to affirm the photographers copyright. Therefore I believe it would be wrong for me or anyone else on this site to assist you in removing these marks.

Comment: Related to ["Convince me to use watermarks"](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/38949/17441) answer (though it's different wording in the actual question).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not constructive to creating photographic works.

Comment: @MichaelClark - Yes, but it does have some value in it, as reference for similar questions in future.

Comment: Please modify your question and add links to the images.  It's possible that some may have been created by contributors to this community and I'm certain they would be keen to offer you (quite specific) advice.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto Closed questions still show up in search, but are no longer answerable.

Comment: I agree with @dav1dsm1th, add links, then the photographers can be informed that you are stealing their images

Comment: I would advise moderators to protect this question but let it here, hoping it will teach something to others. On the other hand, I hope that the OP understand the problem and delete it him/herself.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340910/is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question-because-of-the-askers-intent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get rid of a watermark on a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-a-watermark-on-a-photo)

Answer (score 20):

To echo the words of others, I cannot and will not help you here. You are asking for knowledge on how to remove a copyright owner's SIGNATURE from THEIR WORK. Sorry, but that's wrong. If you want a signature-free copy, you should be contacting the owner of the work to see if they will offer you the right to purchase a COPY — however it is up to them whether they give you that copy without a signature or watermark or not.

This site is run by photographers, artists, some of whom have had their work stolen in the very way you are asking about. You won't get any help here, and to be quite frank...I can only hope to God you don't get any help anywhere else. Sorry.

Comment: +1 for this comment... @shonamoni I'd read this answer and take it on board. If you want to use images you have to buy them or get the appropriate permission. That's why the watermarks are there.