# Is there a way to get rid of a watermark on a photo?

Tags: watermark

I just got married in November and my photographer put a watermark on every photo even though it was agreed to ahead of time not to. How do I get rid of those water marks?

Comment: Have you spoken to the photographer?

Comment: "It was agreed" in writing?

Comment: Depending on your location... you do realise removing yourself is probably illegal right?

Comment: Watermarks are normally put on proofs that are provided *prior to payment for services rendered*.  So to experienced photographers here your question sounds like an attempt to cheat the photographer out of their fee.  If you have a legal agreement in writing or by email and have paid, then you should take legal action.

Comment:        or 24x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a signature from a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/how-do-i-remove-a-signature-from-a-photo)

Answer (score 7):

Not really.

You need to understand that the watermark is not ‘levitating’ above the original picture information, but has *replaced* it. So whatever was in the place where the watermark is now, does no longer exist in the picture you have.

To ‘remove’ the watermark, you can use programs that copy data from nearby over it. Depending on the size and location, that can hide the watermark from a casual observer. But the real data that was there is not recoverable, if you don’t have the picture without the watermark.

Note - as others mentioned - there are potential legal issues with removing it. If you didn’t get what was agreed, you should be able to hold the photographer responsible, but acting yourself might well be illegal.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: pay the photographer the agreed upon rate. He or she will then deliver on the agreed upon photos.

Can *you* remove the watermark? Well, if you have to ask, then you don't have the skill. And even if you did, it would most definitely be immoral and quite possibly be illegal.

I'm sure Dante would rank such an action right next to hypocrisy.